# Select Match column from Difference Table

Tags: c#, sql, variable-assignment

Trying to get title for filtered result
POS club title and Item Title
Filtered record where match memberid and between two date

Here is my table structure

### tblPosClub

- PosClubID
- ClubID
- StaffID
- MemberID
- ItemID
- ItemQuantity
- ItemTotal
- PosClubDate

### tblClub

- ClubID
- ClubTitle
- ClubDesc

### tblItem

- ItemID
- StoreID
- ItemTitle
- ItemDesc
- ItemQuantity
- ItemPrice

I wishing to retrieve

```
      * 
 From tblPosClub
Where (tblPosClub.MemberID = @Memberid) 
  AND (tblPosClub.PosClubDate >= @AfterDate) 
  AND (tblPosClub.PosClubDate < @BeforeDate)
```

...and tblClub.ClubTitle + tblItem.ItemTitle which match according filtered row
may i know what should i modify with this sql command ?

```
    SELECT tblPosClub.PosClubID, 
           tblPosClub.ClubID, 
           tblPosClub.MemberID, 
           tblPosClub.ItemID, 
           tblPosClub.ItemQuantity, 
           tblPosClub.ItemTotal, 
           tblPosClub.PosClubDate, 
           tblClub.ClubTitle, tblItem.ItemTitle
      FROM tblPosClub 
CROSS JOIN tblClub 
CROSS JOIN tblItem
     WHERE (tblPosClub.MemberID = @Memberid) 
       AND (tblPosClub.PosClubDate >= @AfterDate) 
       AND (tblPosClub.PosClubDate < @BeforeDate)
```

Thx in Advance =D

Comment: returning result of pos title for that match that row of pos id and item title that match that row of item id...for example, posid 2 is golf and result posid row for member 1 is 2 then returning golf in result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `INNER JOIN`

```
FROM tblPosClub INNER JOIN tblClub
    ON tblPosClub.ClubID = tblClub.ClubID
  INNER JOIN tblItem
    ON tblPosClub.ItemID = tblItem.ItemID
```

For more information on various join types, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: but this will can't get other club and item @.@, member 1 purchase from club 1, 2, 3 and using this inner join, return club 1 result only...

Comment: @spencer-lim Can you please post the desired results in your question?